# Hackerrank Objective-c int pointer not correct value

Tags: objective-c, integer

If I want an int of an array from an index like: "int value = ar[n]", I always getting huge integers. Which represent the max size of it (I think).

Input (stdin)

```
4
3 2 1 3
```

Code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    int ar[n];
    
    int counter = 0;
    int tempValue;
    
    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
        
       int value = ar[ar_i];
        
        if(tempValue < ar[ar_i]){
            
            counter = 1;
            tempValue = ar[ar_i];
            printf("%i", tempValue);            
        }else if(tempValue == value){
            
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

`printf("%i", tempValue);` for example gives an output "1598483120".
Casting any object to (int) doesn't help.

Did I do something wrong? Or what is going on?

Comment: `tempValue` is uninitialised.

Comment: `int ar[n];` is a local array which is uninitialised.

Comment: My comment was for the C tag. Why is it even there when the question title says "Objective-c"? What does `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` do in C code?

Comment: @WeatherVane - That's not C code, it looks like it started out as the standard Xcode template for an Objective-C command line app. Of course the added code is pretty much pure C, and the issues themselves are pretty much language agnostic... Anyway, that will explain the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `int ar[n]`, but you do not initialize it with values. Accessing uninitialized variables, as you do when writing `int value = ar[ar_i]` then, is undefined behaviour; this often leads to "garbage" values, though other behaviour is - of course - possible as well. The same applies to variable `tempValue`.

So always initialize your variables before accessing them, e.g. with `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) arr[i] = 0;` and `int tempValue=0`.

Note further that - if you are using objective-c - your IDE (XCode probably) might not use C but C++ for your `.mm`-source file; Then a variable-length-array like `int arr[n]` may not be supported.

Comment: Thank you! Your right ar[n] was empty. And i removed "scanf() in the loop (thought that is an output log). Now i know that this methods adds the values to the array. Stupid misstake by my side.